# How to restrict Meteor account creation to an Administrator?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

This can be broken down into two parts:

1) How to specify an account as an administrator?

This is what I have going on right now and it doesn't work.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0) {
        console.log("Adding fake data");
        Accounts.createUser({username:"admin", email:"admin@admin.com", password:"1234", admin: true, profile:{name:"Administrator"}});
     }
```

The "admin" property of the user doesn't work. I'm not sure putting it in the profile is the right thing to do... Any suggestions here?

2) How can I restrict user creation to only administrators?

This is what I have going and it also doesn't work

```
Meteor.users.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
        // only admin and create
        return (userId && Meteor.users(userId).admin);
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

Server side code:

```
Meteor.methods({
    createUser:function(username, email, password, name) {
        if(Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().admin === true) { //You'll have to customize this to how you want it

            return Accounts.createUser({
                       username: username,
                       email: email,
                       password: password,
                       profile: {
                           name: name
                       }
                   });
        }else{
            console.log("not logged in or not an admin");
        }
    },
    makeMeAdmin: function() {
        //You can customize this to have a password or something this is just an example
        Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId}, {$set:{admin:true}});
    }
});
```

Client side code:

Make yourself admin:

```
Meteor.call("makeMeAdmin");
```

Create a user:

```
Meteor.call("createUser", "username", "email@email.com", "password123", "Bob Bob");
```

Comment: It should work. You won't see it client side though because the field is not published. It was just there as an example to show how to use something like that as a condition to update the user. You should use what you were doing before if you find it better

Comment: Sorry to touch a long dated answer, but @Akshat would this send the password in plain text across the wire?

Comment: @Shaded yes, but if you use https/wss it wouldn't

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [authorization](https://github.com/deepwell/meteor-authorization) Atmosphere plugin. It handles role-based authorization and has an example of restricting new user creation to authorized users.

Comment: The meteor-roles package may also be of interest.  The authorization package @Cuberto referenced is a fork of meteor-roles.  The difference is that authorization allows splitting of roles and permissions while roles treats everything equally (basically just tags).  So roles tends to be a bit simpler while authorization allows nesting permissions within roles.
meteor-roles - https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles

Comment: btw, here's the example of restricting new user creation: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/blob/master/examples/mini-pages/server/server.js#L77-L85